# python tox, creating rpm virtualenv, as part of ci pipeline, unsure about where in workflow

Tags: python, jenkins, packaging, tox

I'm investigating how Python applications can also use a CI pipeline, but I'm not sure how to create the standard work-flow.

Jenkins is used to do the initial repository clone, and then initiates tox.  Basically this is where maven, and/or msbuild, would get dependency packages and build.... which tox does via pip, so all good here.

But now for the confusing part, the last part of the pipeline is creating and uploading packages.  Devs would likely upload created packages to a local pip repository, BUT then also possibly create a deployment package.   In this case it would need to be an RPM containing a virtualenv of the application.  I have made one manually using rpmvenev, but regardless of how its made, how what such a step be added to a tox config?  In the case if rpmvenv, it creates its own virtualenv, a self contained command so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like going with the Unix philosophy for this problem. Have a tool that does one thing incredibly well, then compose other tools together. Tox is purpose built to run your tests in a bunch of different python environments so using it to then build a deb / rpm / etc for you I feel is a bit of a misuse of that tool. It's probably easier to use tox just to run all your tests then depending on the results have another step in your pipeline deal with building a package for what was just tested.

Jenkins 2.x which is fairly recent at the time of this writing seems to be much better about building pipelines. BuildBot is going through a decent amount of development and already makes it fairly easy to build a good pipeline for this as well.

What we've done at my work is

- Buildbot in AWS which receives push notifications from Github on PR's
- That kicks off a docker container that pulls in the current code and runs Tox (py.test, flake8, as well as protractor and jasmine tests)
- If the tox step comes back clean, kick off a different docker container to build a deb package
- Push that deb package up to S3 and let [Salt](http://saltstack.com/) deal with telling those machines to update

That deb package is also just available as a build artifact, similar to what Jenkins 1.x would do. Once we're ready to go to staging, we just take that package and promote it to the staging debian repo manually. Ditto for rolling it to prod.

Tools I've found useful for all this:

- [Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) because it's in Python thus easier for us to work on but Jenkins would work just as well. Regardless, this is the controller for the entire pipeline
- Docker because each build should be completely isolated from every other build
- Tox the glorious test runner to handle all those details
- [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) builds the package. RPM, DEB, tar.gz, whatever. Very configurable and easy to script.
- [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) makes it easy to manage debian repositories and in particular push them up to S3.

Comment: While I very much agree on using different tools, doing it build bot is not a practice I can use.   As that would be hard coding the developer pipeline inside the CI, this isn't about finding anyway possible way do CI... But rather about finding a cleanly separated way, the way Maven/MSBuild gives the dev's pipeline power on their side.  Your method sounds very workable for a small-er organization, but my situation the teams are very separated by organizational sprawl. Like the pipeline on the CI side for others is one source clone, build tool start, the rest on devs in source.

Comment: With Jenkins you can use the pipeline plugin to keep a Jenkinsfile in your repo which programmatically defines the pipeline.